# Angular JS binding working only once in the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page where I do multiple binding to the same object `(item, item2, message, messageType)`

Though I placed the binding in several part of the page it works only the first time i placed. The objects are filled with ajax calls that return correctly the value (I logged them in the console)
What sounds even strange to me is that the `<infomessage>` directive has been used in several other places in the app (twice in the same page) and worked perfectly.

Do you have any idea on why these bindings don't work?
I even tried to `$watch` the objects and they are properly changes but seems that the view use the updated value only the first time

```
<div class="container" ng-app="MyApp" >
<div class="row" ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <h3>...</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <infomessage type="{{messageType}}" message="{{message}}"></infomessage>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-10">
        Item: {{item.idbene_ext}} / {{item.id}} / {{item.img}}<br>
        Ubicazione: {{item2.id}} {{item2.code}}
    </div>

</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" ng-class="{'ubiBox':true,'ausilio-enabled':(item!=null),'ausilio-disabled':(item==null), 'boxfocus':(item==null)}">
        <div ng-show="item==null">
            <div class="number">1</div>
            <img src="assets/images/disabled-128.png" width="100" class="img_none"/>
            <h4> {{item.idbene_ext}} Select an item</h4>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="ausilio!=null">
            <h4>Item:{{item.idbene_ext}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"  ng-class="{'ubiBox':true,'ubi-enabled':(item!=null),'ubi-disabled':(item==null),'boxfocus':(item!=null) }">
        <div ng-show="item==null">
            <div class="number">2</div>
            <img src="assets/images/Office-disabled-128.png" width="100" class="img_none"/>
            <h4> Select the second item</h4>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="item!=null">
            <h4>Item2 {{item2.code}}</h4>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <infomessage type="{{messageType}}" message="{{message}}"></infomessage>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-10">
        Item: {{item.idbene_ext}} / {{item.id}} / {{item.img}}<br>
        Ubicazione: {{item2.id}} {{item2.code}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the angularJS code

```
MyApp.controller("MyCtrl",function($scope,$http,Config,BarcodeService){
    $scope.iditem2=-1
    $scope.iditem=-1

    $scope.item2=null
    $scope.item=null

    $scope.message=""
    $scope.messageType=""

    $scope.$on(BarcodeService.handleitem2,function(){
        $scope.message=""
        $scope.messageType=""
        if($scope.item==null){
            $scope.message="select an item before"
            $scope.messageType="error"
        }
        $scope.iditem2=BarcodeService.id    

        $http
            .post(Config.aj,{call:"item2.getitem2",id:$scope.iditem2})
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.item2=data.payload
            })
    })

    $scope.$watch("item",function(){
        console.log("---->",$scope.item)
    },true)

    $scope.$on(BarcodeService.handleitem,function(){
        $scope.message="loading item"
        $scope.messageType="info"
        $scope.iditem=BarcodeService.id
        $http
            .post(Config.aj,{call:"item.getArticoloByIdMin",id:BarcodeService.id})
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.message="item loaded!!"
                $scope.item=data.payload
            })
    })
})
```

Comment: Post the AJAX code you're using

Comment: Are you using angular's `$http` service?

Comment: @wachme I posted the angularJS. The ajax it's a php that return some JSON. The result is correct since I can log it properly in the console

Comment: @ivarni Yes I use the $http service to make POST ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, got it!
The problem was lying in the fact that I have two  in my application but i placed the ng-controller only on the first one.
This caused all the binding in the second div to fail because they were outside the controller.
I moved the ng-controller in the parent div that contains both and now everything works like a charm.
Thanks anyway to @wachme and @ivarni for taking care of my question.
Happy coding to *